# Open, Save, Close, Copy, etc. icons in Studio Code Server?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am using Studio Code Server on Home Assistant (as an add-on).
I am just wondering, is it possible to have some icons, like Open, Save, Close, etc. under menu bar?

I mean something like:
[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jqp5h.png)

I was trying to find relevant option (and via Google), but I didn't find an answer...

Comment: Hi! Found [this extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Scotthew.go-nav-bar), is it what you had on mind?

Comment: Yes, let's say that was the idea. Thank you for the tip.
I couldn't find "Go Nav Bar" in the marketplace (Studio Code Server in Home Assistant)
Instead, I used the Shortcut Menu Bar [link](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=jerrygoyal.shortcut-menu-bar)
Thank you!